# Insert huge data from csv file in .Net framework 4.7.2

Tags: performance, csv, database, asp.net

I need to insert about 500k - 1 million data lines from a CSV file. The time of getting the reports list and insert to database by using `SqlBulkCopy` is very good (10k ~200ms). However, the time to check data validation and add elements to `DataTable` is very slow (10k data ~ 2 minute). I tried many ways but it didn't get any good results...

What should I do to improve my performance in this situation?

```
public ActionResult ConvertFile(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
    st.Start();

    string message = "";

    ConcurrentBag<ImportFailed> listFailed = new ConcurrentBag<ImportFailed>();

    var semesterName = formCollection["SemesterName"];
    var semester = SemestersDAO.GetSemesterByName(semesterName);

    var campusName = formCollection["CampusName"];
    var campus = CampusDAO.GetCampusByName(campusName);

    try
    {
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            string filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

            // Check Header of the file csv if it valid
            var validateHeadersRs = ImportHelper.IsValidHeader(filePath, new CSVStudent().Headers);

            if (validateHeadersRs != null)
            {
                message = $"Error: Missing headers: {validateHeadersRs}";
                ViewBag.Error = message;
                return View();
            }

            string conString = string.Empty;
            conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            // Read CSV
            var reports = ImportHelper.ReadData<CSVStudent>(filePath, modified: false).ToList();
            st.Stop();

            var timeToGetList = st.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            st.Restart();

            DataTable studentDt = new DataTable();
            studentDt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5]
                    {
                        new DataColumn("Email", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Roll", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Full_Name", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Campus_ID", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Semester_ID", typeof(string))
                    });

            DataTable subjectStudentDt = new DataTable();
            subjectStudentDt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3]
                    {
                        new DataColumn("Subject_ID", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Roll", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Semester_ID", typeof(string))
                    });

            int countLine = 1;

            // ProcessData(reports, studentDt, subjectStudentDt, listFailed, semester, campus, countLine);

            # region Parallel
            Parallel.ForEach(reports, report =>
                    {
                        var (isValid, errorMessage) = validateEmail(report.Email);

                        if (!isValid)
                        {
                            listFailed.Add(new ImportFailed
                            {
                                Row = countLine.ToString(),
                                Error = errorMessage
                            });
                        }
                        else if (report.IsAnyEmpty())
                        {
                            listFailed.Add(new ImportFailed
                            {
                                Row = countLine.ToString(),
                                Error = "Data can't be empty!"
                            });
                        }
                        else if (SubjectsDAO.IsExistsSubjectStudent(report.Subject_ID, report.Roll,
                                     semester.Semester_ID))
                        {
                            listFailed.Add(new ImportFailed
                            {
                                Row = countLine.ToString(),
                                Error =
                                    $"Student {report.Roll} and subject {report.Subject_ID} is already exist"
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lock (studentDt)
                            {
                                if (studentDt.AsEnumerable().All(row => report.Roll != row.Field<string>("Roll")))
                                {
                                    DataRow studentRow = studentDt.NewRow();
                                    studentRow["Email"] = report.Email;
                                    studentRow["Roll"] = report.Roll;
                                    studentRow["Full_Name"] = report.Full_Name;
                                    studentRow["Campus_ID"] = campus.Campus_ID;
                                    studentRow["Semester_ID"] = semester.Semester_ID;
                                    studentDt.Rows.Add(studentRow);
                                }
                            }
                            lock (subjectStudentDt)
                            {
                                DataRow row2 = subjectStudentDt.NewRow();
                                row2["Subject_ID"] = report.Subject_ID;
                                row2["Roll"] = report.Roll;
                                row2["Semester_ID"] = semester.Semester_ID;
                                subjectStudentDt.Rows.Add(row2);
                            }
                        }
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref countLine);
                    });

            #endregion

            int subStuBefore = Subject_StudentDAO.CountSubject_Student();
            int countBefore = StudentsDAO.CountNoStudent();
            st.Stop();

            var timeBeforeBulk = st.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            st.Restart();

            if (listFailed.Count <= 0)
            {
                using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default))
                {
                    // Set options for SqlBulkCopy
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                            
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Student";

                    foreach (DataColumn column in studentDt.Columns)
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                    }

                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(studentDt);
                            
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Subject_Student";

                    foreach (DataColumn column in subjectStudentDt.Columns)
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                    }

                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(subjectStudentDt);
                }

                int subStuAfter = Subject_StudentDAO.CountSubject_Student();
                int countAfter = StudentsDAO.CountNoStudent();

                int countAdd = countAfter - countBefore;
                int countFail = studentDt.Rows.Count - countAdd;
                int addSubStu = subStuAfter - subStuBefore;

                st.Stop();

                message = $"Import success {countAdd} student(s), fail {countFail} student(s) and success {addSubStu} subject student(s) in {timeToGetList} - {timeBeforeBulk} - {st.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms";
                        ViewBag.Message = message;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "There's some error in your file. Please check errors below, correct your file and import again!";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        message = e.Message;
        ViewBag.Error = message;
    }

    return View(listFailed);
}
```

Comment: “Very slow” is not a measurement. Tell us: how many rows? how many seconds? What is your target rows-per-second  throughput figure?

Comment: @J_S Oh, sorry, With 10k line data from a csv file, it takes about 2 minutes.

Comment: While not strictly required, it is site standard to tag with the programming language used.

Answer (score 1):

## ACID, profiling

From your `database` tag and the Review Context, I'm assuming
you are using a relational database management system,
likely sqlserver.
You explain that throughput with "SqlBulkCopy is very good",
at 50k row/sec.
And then time to validate + add
will crawl along at just 83 row/sec.

You posted a routine with 193 SLOC,
not breaking out per-line profiling measurements.

Think back on the last 193 menu items you ate for lunch.
Which was the spiciest?
Which was the 40th item?
Which was the longest?
You can't recall?
Yeah neither can I, even though I *just* read
all 193 lines. I can't see them all simultaneously
on my monitor, and I can't hold them all in my mind.
Why is that? Because I am human.
As are all the colleagues you wish to share your technical ideas with.
Write for your audience.
Break large unsolvable problems into small solvable ones.

How do we know the current giant problem is unsolvable?
Because you are asking your colleagues for help.

Maybe your code needs per-row
[ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)
guarantees in real time.
Personally, I am skeptical that your Requirements document
specified that.
I have not yet viewed such project documentation.

We see some timing instrumentation,
but you have chosen not to share those results with reviewers.

## region Parallel

Knuth asks us not to prematurely optimize,
and instead to rely on measurements.
The OP does not describe where observed hot spots are,
so I will brashly assume the region within
`# region Parallel` .. `#endregion`
is (A.) where author *believes* most time is consumed,
and (B.) where observations reveal the time is *actually* consumed.
This is a risky assumption.
Preferably we would have recorded timings to rely on.

Breaking out this region of code as a small helper function
would simplify matters.

## validation

It looks like we call `validateEmail()` and some others.
Not sure how expensive each call is, as OP does not report that.

I **assume** that error rate is "low", and that empty rate is "low",
so we don't spend much time evaluating those nor dealing with
any resulting errors.
Absent per-line profiling figures,
it's hard to validate such an assumption.

## enrollment

```
                studentRow["Roll"] = report.Roll;
```

OK, I'm just going to come out and say it.
I have no idea what the semantics of that assignment might be.

I'm familiar with the notion of **enrollment** of students.
And also how a given student might play the role of a
[TA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_assistant) or
[RA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_assistant).
But here it looks more like a `Role`,
and there's no Review Context or comment documentation
to guide me.
In short, the spelling of that identifier looks like a bug,
a code defect.

## locking

```
                lock (studentDt) ...
                lock (subjectStudentDt) ...
            Interlocked.Increment(ref countLine);
```

I don't know what the cost of those mutex statements is,
because folks who *could* measure it didn't tell me.
But they look expensive.

Batch size is "one record".
An RDBMS can certainly do BEGIN transaction,
UPDATE single_record, COMMIT.
But if you want it do perform a great many such updates per second,
you will want to batch up multiple UPDATEs per COMMIT transaction.

Parallelizing this code is just asking for a proliferation of interacting locks.

A client that loops over a large worklist of pending database requests,
issuing one small request after another, is typically working
*against* the RDBMS's backend planner.
Prefer to expose all million rows to the backend
in the form of an unvalidated `scratch` temporary table
using a single transaction.
The hope is to obtain an improved EXPLAIN SELECT query plan.

## happy path

It seems likely that more than 900k of the 1m rows you're sending
will pass your sanity checks.

Identify such rows up front, and INSERT (or UPDATE) them
in a single transaction.
Then worry about the minority of losing rows.
Since there's only a few, dealing with them won't take much time.

tl;dr: Prefer a few **big** DB transactions, over a million little ones.